# PHP Procedure coding with mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli

I am less familiar with mysqli, and I write Procedure style, not Object orientated style. I know of some of the benefits of object orientated style but it trips my mind so I am slow to adjust with it. My policy is, if I cannot support it, I don't write it.

So... I have a simple function which contains the following:

```
mysqli_query( $DB, "CREATE TABLE $TABLE ( $SCHEMHA )" );

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}
```

The query works when creating the table, so long as I don't have a bug in my schema. If my schema fails, my conditional statement does not trap the failure (thus the connect failed message never gets called).

Where am I going wrong?

My goal is to be able to exit/stop/end on selective errors. So for example, if a table already exists (errno 1050), I am comfortable ignoring that error, however if there is an error 1072 (Key column 'whatever' doesn't exist in table) I would like to stop processing.

All help appreciated...

Comment: No error should ever be ignored...

Comment: Thanks for the comment... but that does not help me with my question...

Comment: Thanks Chris - I want to trap the error number, not the error message. When I have the error number, I can decide which errors I want to ignore (some tables in my test database already exist so hence I only want to stop setup during certain conditions - or ignore during certain conditions depending on point of view).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You'll want to examine the **return value** of `mysqli_query` to know whether the query succeeded or failed.
2. You can get the exact error code using `mysqli_errno`.
3. The `_connect_` functions you're using are irrelevant in this context, they give you information about errors which happened during a **connection** attempt.

```
if (!mysqli_query(..)) {
    switch (mysqli_errno($DB)) {
        case 1072:
            ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Fred, I swear this autocorrect is driving me insane sometimes.

Comment: Thank you Good Sir! I raise my hat, bow my head in appreciation =)

Answer (score 2):

The `mysqli_connect_errno` returns the error from the connection. Your error is resulting in the query though so use [mysqli_error](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php).

```
if (mysqli_error($DB)) {
    printf("Errormessage: %s\n", mysqli_error($link));
}
```

If you just want to check the error code use http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.errno.php.

```
printf("Errorcode: %d\n", mysqli_errno($DB));
```

To check for specific codes you could do:

```
if(in_array(mysqli_errno($DB), array(1072, other codes)) {
    exit('Bad Code');
} else {
    echo 'Still processing...';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> So for example, if a table already exists (errno 1050), I am comfortable ignoring that error,

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS $TABLE ...
```

Answer (score -1):

I believe something like this would do:

```
$result = mysqli_query( $DB, "CREATE TABLE $TABLE ( $SCHEMHA )" );

if (!$result) {
    switch(mysqli_connect_error()) {
        // Key column 'whatever' doesn't exist in table
        case 1072:
            printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
            exit();
            break;
        // and so on... 
    }
}
```

Comment: Nope - that did not work - no errors in my php log file, no errors to the screen, the code ran and ignored anything inside the if conditional statement. (I am using PHP 5.5.7)